# Lotus/IBM Domino Server SSL Configuration for Multiple Internet Sites

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lotus-domino, lotus

Having trouble assigning SSL certificates for more than one domain using Internet Site documents.  The SSL keys work individually using Web Configuration (not Internet Site docs), and somewhere along the process of testing Internet Site docs I got both sites using their respective SSL certs briefly, but shortly thereafter it stopped working again.

When using Internet Sites, one SSL key ends up being assigned to all the domains rather than one key per domain.  Fix Pack 10 has been installed on the server.  Directory Assistance manages 2 separate Address books for each domain, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Ideas?

Comment: Just curious but wouldn't [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) be a better site for this question? Stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately the expected behavior on Domino. Only one SSL enabled Internet Site document is allowed per IP address.

See this tech note for details: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21173919

Also see my answer to a similar question on Serverfault: https://serverfault.com/a/375106

You need to set up a front end proxy such as Nginx in order to run multiple internet sites with their own SSL certificate on one IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that both (all?) domains are assigned to the same IP address in DNS. If you have the option to modify DNS enties, a way to achieve multiple SSLs on the same Domino server is to

1) have the each domain assigned to different IP addresses in DNS and

2) have the Domino server listening to two (or more) IP addresses.

Then you can configure two (or more) separate Internet Sites for the separate IP addresses and configure you SSLs on each Internet Site.